# Cannot set prototype of SpeechSynthesisVoice manually

Tags: javascript, speech-synthesis, webspeech-api

This question is somewhat for understanding the prototype get-set.

I've a scenario where I need to map the **SpeechSynthesis** supported voice to **Google Translation API** supported language codes.
For example,

> [image]

Now, I can do the same by either fetching the voices runtime or by storing the voice and hard-coding the mapping in some method in javascript.
If I go for runtime approach, I need to call `getVoice()` in `speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = () => {}` and then map the numbers, which gets called in every voice change event. So, I want to go for hard-coding one.

Now, when I store the mapping array in a variable and call it by index, I get the SpeechSynthesisVoice Object, just like what we do in `getVoices()[index]`.

Further, If I set this object value to `speechSynthesis.voice`, I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'voice' property on 'SpeechSynthesisUtterance': The provided value is not of type 'SpeechSynthesisVoice'.
```

This is due to mis-match of prototype of the manually stored object value.

For example,

**1. SpeechSynthesisVoice object:**

> [image]

**2. Manually stored value of SpeechSynthesisVoice object:**

> [image]

To resolve, this I've fetched the **proto** of the SpeechSynthesisVoice object using `getVoice()`, and then set it to a variable and further, set this variable to my manual mapped object.
Like,

Get:

```
voicePrototype = getVoices()[9].__proto__;
```

Set:

```
voices[index].SpeechSynthesisVoice.__proto__ = voicePrototype;
```

And, it gets set, as in below screenshot:

> [image]

I've also tried through `Object.setPrototypeOf()` and got the same result.

Now, again when I want to set this object to `speechSynthesis.voice`, I still get the same error, although my prototype matches.

Can anyone, please advise, if its possible to set the object proto likewise and use it? Thanks in advance.